# Linux Password expired , getting Access Denied message

Tags: linux

A very good day to all of you out there .

Generally i would be connecting to Remote Linux Machine using my Username and Password , few days back i got a message saying my Password would expire within 5 days , anyway i have ignored it and didn't pay attention .

Now after 7 days  , and when i tried  to connect to the Linux  Remote Machine  using my user name and password , i am getting message as  **Access Denied** .

Please tell me is there any case i can login again  using my account ??

Comment: Wrong forum to ask. But you should contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 3):

There is not. Contact the administrator of the remote machine and ask for a new password.